# Where to configure Jenkins plugins?

Tags: jenkins

I am unable to find where to configure just-installed Jenkins plugin.

Is there a common place somewhere where Jenkins plugins are installed?

Plugin: [Secure Requester Whitelist](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Secure+Requester+Whitelist+Plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure this plugin in the following admin section:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can go to **Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins**.
Download plugins from **Available Plugins** Tab in **.hpi** format and then u can upload via browsing the file from **Advanced Tab**.
Once successfully uploaded, **restart the Jenkins** by checking the checkbox on the UI.
The plugin will be installed in your **/{Jenkins_Home}/plugins/** folder.

Hope this helps.